# help with proof for Normalized fundamental matrices: $\Psi(t)A = A \Psi(t)$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

There was no proof provided for theorem 2 and I would like to know how they go to it.

The matrix $A$ is a constant matrix.

**Theorem 1:** If $\Psi$ is a normalized fundamental matrix of $X' = AX$ at $t_0 = 0$, then

$\Psi(s + t) = \Psi(t)\Psi(s)$

for all real numbers $s$ and $t$.

**Theorem 2:** If $\Psi$ is a normalized fundamental matrix of $X'=AX$ at $t_0$, then

$A\Psi(t)=\Psi(t)A$

**I can do it for normalized fundamental matrix at $t_0 = 0$ only**

I can prove it if $t_0 = 0$ with the aid of the theorem 1:

using theorem 2,

$\frac{d}{ds}\Psi(s + t) = \frac{d}{ds}(\Psi(t)\Psi(s)) = \frac{d}{ds}(\Psi(t))\Psi(s) + \Psi(t)\frac{d}{ds}\Psi(s)$

$\\ \\= \Psi(t)\frac{d}{ds}\Psi(s)$

$\\ \\= \Psi(t)A\Psi(s)$

now I guess $\Psi(s + t) = e^{A(s+t)}$

thus $\frac{d}{ds}\Psi(s + t) = Ae^{A(s+t)}$

thus $Ae^{A(s+t)} = \Psi(t)A\Psi(s)$

at $s = 0$,

$Ae^{A(t)} = \Psi(t)A\Psi(0)$

now as $\Psi$ is a normalized fundamental matrix at $t_0 = 0$,

$Ae^{A(t)} = \Psi(t)A$

$\implies A\Psi(t) = \Psi(t)A$

Now I would like to use this for any $t_0$, but theorem 2 only works for $t_0 = 0$

I would greatly appreciate it if you could show me how they did it.